# Removing multiple items from QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qlist

In my Qt GUI, I have `QGraphicsScene` where `QGraphicsItems` are added. Now in order to delete the items, I'm using `GraphicsScene::selectedItems()` to return a list of items selected on the screen. This returns the memory address of selected items, their position and flag as a comma separated array.

Now how do I use this result `"QList<QGraphicsItem*>` as an argument to `QGraphicsScene::removeItem()`?

UPDATE ****
Item added to the scene is from a class derived from GraphicsItem. And each class creates a text file when the item saddled to the scene. So when this item is deleted the text file also should be deleted. If I'm gonna use the above method, I cant do that. Rather I prefer to get the object being selected by QGraphicsScene::selectedItems and then use the member function from the class to delete the file associated with it. How do I do this. Please explain thank you so much

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting a QGraphicsItem/QGraphicsObject from QGraphicsScene?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905718/deleting-a-qgraphicsitem-qgraphicsobject-from-qgraphicsscene)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (QGraphicsItem * i, selectedItems()) removeItem(i);
```

Comment: Bro, each item added to the scene is from a class derived from GraphicsItem. And each class creates a text file when the item saddled to the scene. So when this item is deleted the text file also  should be deleted. If I'm gonna use the above method, I cant do that. Rather I prefer to get the object being selected by QGraphicsScene::selectedItems and then use the member function from the class to delete the file associated with it. How do I do this. Please explain thank you so much :)

Comment: Remove the file in the item destructor... and after `removeItem(i)` also call `delete i`. `removeItem(i)` doesn't delete the item, only removes it from that particular screne.